# Vsiual Studio for mac Error Msg Xamarin.forms tasks donot match targets

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms

Err Msg:
Xamarin.forms tasks donot match targets. Please ensure that all projects reference the same version of xamarin forms.

I Just Updated Xamarin.forms version to : 3.0.0.482510
My Vs for mac verion : 7.3.2 (build 12)

when compiled I got above error msg.

How to solve this problem?

How to navigate to CSProj file in Visual Studio for mac?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you have this kind of problems:

1) Delete obj and bin folders of all your projects
2) Restart Visual Studio
3) Perform a Rebuild on Solution

It fixes 99% of compilation errors